# Why my fixture is not installing on django project?

Tags: django, psycopg2, django-fixtures

I created a backup of database using fixtures in my django project by following command:-

```
python manage.py dumpdata > db.json
```

when i load the fixture, i get following error:-

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '/home/gagan/saporawebapp/webapp/fixtures/db.json': Could not load contenttypes.ContentType(pk=17): duplicate key value violates unique constraint "django_content_type_app_label_model_76bd3d3b_uniq"
```

DETAIL:  Key (app_label, model)=(webapp, homescreen) already exists.
I don't know how integrity erros arises even  when i'm just loading the fixture. How can i solve this error?
**Edit**
I figured it out because i forget to exclude auth.permission and contenttypes while dumping my database but i still do not know how to rectify it?

Comment: Edit your thread with details from db.json

Comment: db.json is just a json file which holds database from django project. I do not understand about what detail you want to see from db.json @Harben

Answer (score 1):

If you are in django>=1.11 try remove stale content types before exporting backup

```
python manage.py remove_stale_contenttypes
```

Answer (score 0):

your content-type table in your db has a record with duplicate app_label, and different pk, app_label is unique and you can't insert new value with existing app_label